# Failed to bind properties under " to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:" Springboot

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, maven, ojdbc

I have already added ojdbc ddriver and included the dependency in pom, but I still get the error mentioned in the title. Please help.

Earlier I ran the application with a local postgres db. Now trying to connect to a remote oracle db, and encountered this problem. I am logged into the necessary firewalls.
The appplication started and performed as exected with the postgresdb.

I get the following logs when trying to start my application now -

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-06 12:08:51.786 ERROR 27236 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

    Property: driverclassname
    Value: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
    Reason: Failed to load driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

Action:

Update your application's configuration


Process finished with exit code 1
```

The pom file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
        <groupId>package</groupId>
    <artifactId>QualityScore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>QualityScore</name>
    <description>Demo project in Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application.properties -

```
##Postgres settings
##spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:*****
##spring.datasource.username=*****
##spring.datasource.password=*****
##spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true

# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:*****
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.datasource.driver-class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

# HikariCP settings
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5

#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Comment: Can you post your **application.properties**  file?

Comment: Added application.properties

Comment: Check my answer. And give a response after checking.

Comment: You wrote comment on pom.xml  **(I removed this stuff, but they should not matter, if required please request in comments)** . Which one you commented ?

Comment: <groupId>package</groupId>
 <artifactId>QualityScore</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>QualityScore</name>
 <description>Demo Projectin Spring Boot</description>

Comment: @AvjitBarua, I have added the commented out section, and like I said the same old problem persists and a new one has arisen, I get an error in pom.xml - "Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.oracle:ojdbc8:jar:unknown"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution or fix.
I added the following property in application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

and explicitly specified the driver(ojdbc8) in the modules of the project structure.
Now it works!!! Thank you everyone for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

you application.properties is wrong. You have:

```
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:*****
#spring.datasource.username=****
#spring.tasource.password=*****
#spring.jpa.database-platform = *****
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:****
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****

#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

Recipientlist=*****
```

but you don't have your driver-class-name set. should be:

```
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:*****
#spring.datasource.username=****
#spring.tasource.password=*****
#spring.jpa.database-platform = *****
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:****
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

Recipientlist=*****
```

Regards!

Comment: Hi, I added the property(...OracleDriver) as you mentioned, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In my controller test classes, this error occurred when running the tests. Even with the `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` property set.

To resolve this, we added the `DataSouce` attribute with the `@MockBean` annotation in the controller test classes:

```
 @MockBean
 private DataSource dataSource;
```

The test classes performed perfectly.